# Not able to import Mockito library into my Test Classes

Tags: java, gradle, mocking, mockito, junit5

[Source Code Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lXEd.jpg)**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}
ext {
    buildId = System.currentTimeMillis()
    codinGameMainClass = "com.codingame.App"
}
group = 'com.coding-game-problem'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
java {
    sourceCompatibility = '8'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.11.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
}

test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
        def destinationDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.gradle/daemon/${buildId}/test-results"
        junitXml.destination = file(destinationDirectory)
        html.enabled = true
    }
    useJUnitPlatform {
    }
    testLogging.events ("STANDARD_ERROR")
    testLogging.events ("STANDARD_OUT")
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
        if (!desc.parent) {
            println "\nTEST RESULT: ${result.resultType}"
            println "TEST SUMMARY: RAN ${result.testCount} TESTS, " +
                    "${result.successfulTestCount} SUCCEEDED, " +
                    "${result.failedTestCount} FAILED, " +
                    "${result.skippedTestCount} SKIPPED"
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

In my **Test Class**, following lines of code is not able to import Mockito library, giving compile time errors as dependency is not resolved:

```
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@DisplayName("ContestServiceTest")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

After performing ./gradlew build, getting complile time issues in Test Classes.
Kindly help on this....

Comment: Please show your source code structure.

Comment: SourceCodeStructure added in build.gradle

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I am able to run your above setup perfectly. Although, I did my setup in spring boot project

Comment: My set up is a simple gradle project...

Comment: Actually I tried it as well, it is working as well

Comment: You are adding the test class under src/test/java right?

Comment: tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
} 
Should be redundant.

Comment: Which Gradle version are you using? Have you tried through a wrapper?

Comment: yes that is true

Comment: Gradle version is 8.2.1

Comment: yes I am building project using Gradle Wrapper

Comment: is there anything to do with Module or Directory ??

Answer (score 1):

mockito-junit-jupiter is just the extension for mockito. You need to add mockito-core itself:

```
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:4.11.0")
```

Comment: Already tried with Mockito core as well. Issue still persists.
Now build.gradle looks like below:


dependencies {
 testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.11.0'
 testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.11.0'
 testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
}